# C++ initialize lists as NULL in matrix

Tags: c++, arrays, list, pointers, null

I'm new to c++ and I got really confused about stuff like pointers and NULL.

I need to set a 2d array of lists of pointers to object I created. I want the lists to set to NULL as I created my object. I got an error when I tried to run it. I'm not sure if it is because I did something wrong with the pointers or with the NULL. I would appreciate any help.

here is my code:

GameFullMatrix.h:

```
private:
    std::list<InGame*>** fullMap;
    int rows,cols;
```

GameFullMatrix.cpp:

```
GameFullMatrix::GameFullMatrix(int _rows, int _cols)
{
    this->fullMap = new std::list<InGame*>*[_rows];

    for(int i=0; i<_rows; i++)
    {
        this->fullMap[i] = new std::list<InGame*>[_cols];
        for(int j=0; j<_cols; j++)
        {
            this->fullMap[i][j] = NULL;
        }
    }

this->rows = _rows;
this->cols = _cols;
}
```

the error I get when I try to build the code:

> no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::list’ and
>   ‘long int’)|

thanks.

Comment: Why do you have a double pointer to a `std::list`?  If you need dynamic arrays use `std::vector`.

Comment: I see no need for pointers here. You should use `std::vector` for `fullMap` instead.

Comment: As for the errors, there's no need for the assignment. A newly create `std::list` object will be empty. It is also an *object* and not a pointer, and so you simply can't try to set the object to `NULL`.

Comment: What are you confused about? The error message states exactly what's wrong: `fullMap[i][j]` is of type `std::list<InGame*>`, and, since it's an object, and not a pointer, you cannot assign `NULL` to it (technically NULL is typically defined as `0`, which can be treated as an `int`, consider using `nullptr` if your compiler supports C++11).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude what is the benefits of using 2 vectors instead of 2d array? there is a good reason to prefer using vectors?

Comment: Ease of use, no risk of memory leaks, easier to pass around, easier to iterate, no need to store the size explicitly. Among others. With modern C++ there's often no need for pointers outside of polymorphism.

Comment: @Moshe9362 No manual memory management? E.g. No need to worry about memory allocation, copying, memory deallocation.

Comment: thanks guys, I will work on it. I will use vectors instead as you suggest

Comment: @NathanOliver "Why do you have a double pointer to a list" that is the stuff of nightmares.

Comment: @Borgleader I thought that was `int* (*process)(int***, int)[];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fullMap[i][j]` is of type `std::list<InGame*>` you cannot directly insert data into list by assignment operator. you need to use `fullMap[i][j].push_back(NULL)` or `fullMap[i][j].push_front(NULL)`

(assignment operator in std:list is overloaded to copy content of one list to another list, `std::list<InGame*> abc= some variable of type std::list<InGame*>` will work )

But why you need to insert NULL into list, you can always check if list is empty by `fullMap[i][j].empty()`